# Web-Form Rendering Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've got a traditional User Control, I have the following structure:

```html
<asp:Content id="ContentBody" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderId="MainContent">
    <Core:AccountApplication id="uxAccountApplication" runat="server" />
</asp>
```

Inside the User Control I have a traditional:

```html
<form id="AccountForm">
    <input type="text" id="txtCompany" name="Company" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

The problem occurs when I call `$('#AccountForm').serialize();` the request is constantly empty, nothing is serialized.  If I do `$('form').serialize();` it does serialize, but it also grabs all of the Web-Form `ViewState` rendering.  Which requires some dubious approaches to correct.

Is there a better way to tackle?

Comment: Could you post the actual HTML of your ASP control. It sounds like the `#AccountForm` selector is incorrect. Also to avoid serialising the ViewState data you would need to manually serialise the form.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It isn't an asp control, it is all native HTML with no `runat="server"` in the User Control.

Comment: `<Core:AccountApplication id="uxAccountApplication" runat="server" />` ... ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is to Register the User Control.

Comment: Either way we can't help you without seeing your HTML.

Comment: @Greg If possible, you can try changing `<form>` to some container like `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested forms are not allowed in ASP.NET (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384350/why-net-strips-off-one-form-tag-from-the-page-if-there-is-already-a-form-with) for example).

Your `<form id="AccountForm">` element will be removed by ASP.NET (look at the generated HTML to confirm that).

Comment: I was noticing that it was removed, there isn't any way?

Comment: @Greg: haven't tested it, but try this: replace the `form` element with a `<div id="AccountForm">` and use `$('#AccountForm input').serialize()`.

Comment: You're correct about the removal, after I saw that I decided to use a `wrap()` in jQuery.  Which worked.

Answer (score 0):

After the answer received where it was denoted that the form element is removed, I verified and the entire form was indeed removed.  So I did the following:

```
<div class="Application-Container">
     <!-- All my form inputs -->
</div>
```

Wrapped them into a container, then I used jQuery to wrap the container into a form.

```
$('.Application-Container').wrap('<form id="AccountForm"></form>');
```

Now when you submit, it will rewrap into the form, then I can call `$('#AccountForm').serialize()` and it will correctly build my form data.